# Osticket Department Email ID

Tags: php, zend-framework, soap

I want to fetch the `ost_department email_id` 
I have used the following method

```
$args1 = array( 'username'        => $this->osticket->username,
                'password'        => $this->osticket->password,
                'departmentId'    => $dept->id
              );

try { 
    $getmail = $osticket->__call('ostDepartment.getInfo',$args1); 

    echo '<pre>', print_r($getmail);exit;
} catch(SoapFault $e) {
    $error  = true;
}
```

Here is the output for my echo

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 3
    [name] => bcod
    [email] => Support
    [isPublic] => 1
)
1
```

Through these details how can I fetch the department email id i,e support@yourdomain.com from department table of osticket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this

```
$dept->getEmailId()
```

and this

```
$dept->getEmail()
```